# Play store shows ITEM NOT found after clicking the rate button in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a **rate** button in untiy3d and onclick that button it redirects  to Playstore but shows the error **"item not found"**.

I have attached following C# code to my rate button

```
   public void RateUs()
{
    Application.OpenURL("market://details?id=com.domainname.gamename");
}
```

By replacing `com.domainname.gamename` by my game package name but it doesn't work.
Any Help would be great.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, is your game published to the Play Store? If not, then the link won't work. Try the same on browser by using the following url: [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.app)

Comment: Yes it is published And still shows the error.

Comment: Google Play Console has a button that says "view in play store" open that and copy the link.